# Making a COM object visible to iis/classic asp in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, asp-classic

In this question, I explained I was trying to create a com object with visual studio 2010

[Struggling creating a COM object with Visual Studio 2010 which is visible from VBScript run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818572/struggling-creating-a-com-object-with-visual-studio-2010-which-is-visible-from-v)

The answer, related to use of the 32 bit script interpreter for the com object solved the problem for accessing the object from a a console script.

I have now tried to move forward and have improved the script and rebuilt it, and am now trying to test in in a Classic ASP environment.  This is set up with IIS7.

Again I am hitting a brick wall with the error "ActiveX component can't create object" error message.  (I can still call it with my script using the wow64 script interpreter, although the object has moved on and has more complicated interfaces etc, so it pretty soon fell over when trying to use the object.)

I've tried the advice here

[Visual Studio 2010 64-bit COM Interop Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450509/visual-studio-2010-64-bit-com-interop-issue)

and read loads of articles about what should be in the registry.  The entries are all there, and yet I still get the error.

Anyone any ideas how I can proceed

UPDATE

In IIS Manager selecting the Application Pool which is the one running the particular site I was accessing, under Advanced Settings there is an "Enable 32 bit applications". This changed the error message to  "006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~80070002".

I then moved the entire Visual Studio Project which is the com object from a network drive to the local C: drive and the error message became "The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object."

I've tried to fix the permissions issue in two ways.

- I have changed the security on the directory where the built DLL and tlb files reside to allow the user the application pool runs under (its using ApplicationPoolIdentity) rights to read and execute (this had no effect)
- I have tried changing the user that the application pool ran under to myself (who is in the Administrators group) so that it could access everything.  In this case I would get a 503 error and the application pool would stop, although I could find nothing in the logs to say why, despite having Failed Tracking turned on.

So I am still without an answer.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Initially I was getting the error mentioned in the question.  I've moved the comm object from a Network drive to the local C:drive and now I get "The call to Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object."

Comment: @akc42 On top of granting access to "the user that the application pool ran under", you could also try granting access to the users "Network" and "Network Services"

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We are having the same issue.

Comment: I didn't get it resolved from the perspective of IIS locally.  Instead I used a "RAZOR" app, which looked like the original ASP and visual studio ran that and called the object successfully from its own controlled web server.